# Latch edge and Launch edge of a clock

Tags: digital-logic, latch

Why does a Destination register starts taking input from a latch edge and not a launch edge

Comment: The "what is" questions are best answered by Google.

Comment: @EugeneSh.Is it the like +ve edge or -ve edge of a clock pulse?

Comment: FYI, if you accept an early answer you'll discourage other people from giving more answers. You can wait 24 hours to let people all around the world see your question. Especially if you don't understand an answer, you shouldn't click the "accept" button for that answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does a Destination register starts taking input from a latch edge and not a launch edge

Because "latch edge" means "the edge where the destination register *latches* the signal in".

"Launch edge" means "the edge where the source register *launches* the signal onto the wire". The launch edge is an edge of a clock signal that is available at the source. The destination register might not even be connected to the clock signal that provides the launch edge.

Answer (score -2):

It's used for doing critical race timing analysis.
http://www.ee.bgu.ac.il/~digivlsi/slides/STA_9_1.pdf

Comment: I 'm not able to figure out from the document.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. Value at Q end of source register will change at launch edge but it wont be captured at destination register due to path delay. At the next +ve aka latct edge data will be captued at destination register.

Comment: Yes you got the idea but it seems someone doesn't like my brief answer with a link.  (-1 troll)

Comment: Maybe because you don't answer the question, link-only answers are frowned on and you can't even click on the link?

Comment: it takes 10 seconds to copy and paste for a much better answer than anyone else could even imagine giving (-10 for the lazy other peeps who haven't learned how to learn and -100 for those who want free ideal answers) but I understand those that frown. (+1) to those that agree. We are not here to spoon-feed. and dead links may be archived by google and archive.org and will be found replicated elsewhere by the document name